# Is there any homeopathic solution for heredomacula degeneration

Tags: eye

its difficult to see small object like pencil,eraser,key. Eye Specialist said there is no solution for this disorder.

Answer (score 3):

Homeopathy is a pseudosience with no proven effectiveness in treating any condition. Degenerative diseases are hard to treat, but don't lose hope that new research will discover a treatment that works in the future. In the meantime, looking for "alternative" cures will not only leave your eyes the same, it will also hurt your wallet.